# Is there any way to call the OnPaint() method after certain conditions have been cleared?

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

My desktop is really messy at the moment so I decided to create a program where you can drag a file it and it creates a shortcut. When the file is dragged in, I grab the file's icon and name and save it, then draw them to the WinForm through OnPaint(). I'm having trouble with this though, since even before I can drag the file into the form, the OnPaint() draws a huge red X and doesn't update. Here is my code (it's a picture):

[image]

And the OnPaint method:

[image]

My question is that is there anyway to delay the OnPaint() method to wait until it acquires  the certain data it needs to draw properly, or any other drawing method I could use to paste the icon+file name to the WinForm?

P.S: I've tried using Thread.Sleep, but then I realized it sleeps the main thread so the Drag/Drop processes can't occur

Comment: What about just calling `this.Invalidate()` after the drag drop? The big red X is because its drawing a null picture. Invalidating the form afterwards will re-fire the paint event.. which should then have your `ico` variable properly initialized.

Comment: You get the Big Red X when your OnPaint() method throws an exception.  There are obvious candidates, kaboomX when icon or filename are still null.  So test for that.  Your DragDrop() event handler must call `this.Invalidate();` to trigger a repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

The first is what I said in my comment.. invalidate the form to cause `OnPaint` to be recalled after the drag drop:

```
foreach (string path in filePath)
{
    // your other code here (PS: Paste code next time)
}

this.Invalidate();
```

Your other option.. is to use a flag that you can check in `OnPaint`:

```
bool canDraw = false;

// dragdrop event:

foreach (string path in filePath)
{
    // your other code here (PS: Paste code next time)
}

canDraw = true;

// OnPaint:

if (canDraw) {
    // do your painting here

    canDraw = false;
}

base.OnPaint(e); // make sure you defer to the base painting method too
```

The second option effectively delays your painting until you say its okay.. but only your custom painting. You leave the `base.OnPaint` call out of your conditional so that it can always paint when it needs to.